# python3 -m datahub version

Tags: python-3.x, pip, datahub

I install datahub on Linux,i executed a command

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade acryl-datahub
```

,after that,i want to show the version,then i executed a command

```
python3 -m datahub version
```

this command reported an error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 194, in
> _run_module_as_main
> return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,   File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
> exec(code, run_globals)   File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/datahub/**main**.py",
> line 1, in 
> from datahub.entrypoints import main   File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/datahub/entrypoints.py",
> line 18, in 
> from datahub.cli.docker_cli import docker   File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/datahub/cli/docker_cli.py",
> line 595, in 
> def quickstart(  # noqa: C901   File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/decorators.py",
> line 373, in decorator
> _param_memo(f, cls(param_decls, **attrs))   File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line
> 2536, in **init**
> super().**init**(param_decls, type=type, multiple=multiple, **attrs)   File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line
> 2114, in **init**
> self.type: types.ParamType = types.convert_type(type, default)   File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/types.py",
> line 1056, in convert_type
> return FuncParamType(ty)   File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/types.py", line
> 166, in **init**
> self.name: str = func.**name**   File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.8/typing.py", line 760, in **getattr**
> raise AttributeError(attr)

My environment is：

centos: 7.9
python version: 3.8.3
pip version: pip 23.3.2 from /usr/local/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)

The document I am referring to is : https://datahubproject.io/docs/quickstart/

I hope to run a datahub service，thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix the issue by specifying the datahub version to install as below:

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade acryl-datahub==0.12.1
```

As per documentation if we just run the below, v0.12.0 is being installed which seems to be running in to the issue you specified

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade acryl-datahub
```